# How to remove special characters like a single quote from a string?

Tags: regex, linux, perl, shell

Using Sed I tried but it did not worked out.
Basically, I have a string say:-

Input:-

`'http://www.google.com/photos'`

Output required:-

`http://www.google.com`

I tried using sed but escaping ' is not possible.
what i did was:- 
sed 's/\'//'  | sed 's/photos//'

sed for photos worked but for ' it didn't.
Please suggest what can be the solution.

Comment: Try `sed "s/'//g"`

Comment: @GeorgeVasiliou: See http://ideone.com/pSmb3l

Answer (score 0):

Escaping ' in sed **is** possible *via a workaround*:

```
sed 's/'"'"'//g'
#      |^^^+--- bash string with the single quote inside
#      |   '--- return to sed string 
#      '------- leave sed string and go to bash
```

But for this job you should use tr:

```
tr -d "'"
```

Answer (score 0):

Perl Replacements have a syntax identical to sed, works better than sed, is installed almost in every system by default and works for all machines the same way (portability):

```
$ echo "'http://www.google.com/photos'" |perl -pe "s#\'##g;s#(.*//.*/)(.*$)#\1#g"
http://www.google.com/
```

Mind that this solution will keep only the domain name with http in front, discarding all words following http://www.google.com/

If you want to do it with sed , you can use sed "s/'//g" as advised by Wiktor Stribiżew in comments.
PS: I sometimes refer to special chars with their ascii hex code of the special char as advised by `man ascii`, which is `\x27` for `'`

So for sed you can do it:

```
$ echo "'http://www.google.com/photos'" |sed -r "s#'##g; s#(.*//.*/)(.*$)#\1#g;"
http://www.google.com/
# sed "s#\x27##g' will also remove the single quote using hex ascii code.

$ echo "'http://www.google.com/photos'" |sed -r "s#'##g; s#(.*//.*)(/.*$)#\1#g;"
http://www.google.com      #Without the last slash
```

If your string is stored in a variable, you can achieve above operations with pure bash, without the need of external tools like sed or perl like this:

```
$ a="'http://www.google.com/photos'" && a="${a:1:-1}" && echo "$a"
http://www.google.com/photos
# This removes 1st and last char of the variable , whatever this char is.    

$ a="'http://www.google.com/photos'" && a="${a:1:-1}" && echo "${a%/*}"
http://www.google.com
#This deletes every char from the end of the string up to the first found slash /. 
#If you need the last slash you can just add it to the echo manually like echo "${a%/*}/" -->http://www.google.com/
```

Answer (score -1):

It's unclear if the `'` are actually around your string, although this should take care it:

```
str="'http://www.google.com/photos'"
echo "$str" | sed s/\'//g | sed 's/\/photos//g'
```

Combined:

```
echo "$str" | sed -e "s/'//g" -e 's/\/photos//g'
```

Using `tr`:

```
echo "$str" | sed -e "s/\/photos//g" | tr -d \'
```

**Result**:

```
http://www.google.com
```

If the single quotes are not around your string it should work regardless.